# How to get key in a object

Tags: java, android

I have this code

```
lv.setClickable(true);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Log.d(TAG, o.toString());
    }
});
```

My goal is when the user click on the listview item i want to log cat the IdNotificacao.

but what i get in logcat is this:

```
{PrioridadeDescr=Normal, Titulo=Cliente de Testes da CliCloud v3: Erro ao ler RSS de ************, AddDate=02/02/2017, TipoDescr=Plugin RSS, IdNotificacao=5199}
```

I only want to logcat the IdNotificacao=5199.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What **kind** of Object `lv.getItemAtPosition(position)` returns?

Comment: Override the `toString` method of your class to match the format you want

Comment: @AxelH  i'm new at java android, i don't know how to do that. Can you do it please and post as an answer?

Comment: @mallaudin i get this return "{PrioridadeDescr=Normal, Titulo=Cliente de Testes da CliCloud v3: Erro ao ler RSS de ************, AddDate=02/02/2017, TipoDescr=Plugin RSS, IdNotificacao=5199}"

Comment: You are new and learning with Android how to use Java ? That not a good idea ;) Search **How to override toString method in Java**

Comment: there are too many answers. you can pick one. Override `toString` in your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Object.toString()` method in the logcat.

You can simply override the method of the specific class you are using in this list.

Since every class extends `Object`, congratulation, you have override a method!

```
public MyClass {

    int IdNotificao;

   ...

    public String toString(){
        return "IdNotificao : " + IdNotificao;
    }
}
```

Note : If this is to complicate for you, stop learning Android and start by the basic of Java, heritance, inner classes, are extremly used in Android.

Answer (score 0):

In your model class which you are getting from list, override the toString method and return only the IdNotificao.

Comment: yeah... i'm really new at java android, i don't know how to do that. Can you do it please?

Comment: Yes I can but I cannot do it with only this much of code.

Answer (score 0):

Call it this way :

```
Log.d(TAG, ((ClassName)o).IdNotificacao + "");
```

Comment: @PinTelele The name of class/model that contains the attribute IdNotificacao